# Sort with custom pattern?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort

Rather than sorting based on a-z, is it possible to sort based on occurrence?

Example of desired task,

Input =

```
Example
Example
Hello
Hello
Input
Input
List
List
World
World
...
```

Desired output =

```
Example
Hello
Input
List
World
Example
Hello
Input
List
World
...
```

So in this scenario it gets the first occurrence of each line and puts them in order, then the second occurrence of each line and puts them in order until there's no more occurences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the decorate - sort - undecorate  approach:

```
<input awk -v OFS=: '{print ++n[$0], $0}' |
  sort -t: -k1,1n -k2 |
  cut -d: -f2-
```

Where `awk` prepends each line with the line's occurrence as a number for `sort` to sort on as its first `k`ey (numeric order), and the original line as the second key (default locale collation order).

Here using `:` as the separator instead of `awk`'s default SPC and `sort`'s default transition from a non-blank to a blank as with that default, the SPC would be included in the second key which might (unlikely) have an impact on sorting.

Comment: You mentioned separator's, would I use the same command if I wanted to sort based on first and/or second field/column?

Comment: @Bash, you could, you'd need to set the `FS` variable of `awk` to specify how *input* fields are separated (`OFS` is the *output* field separator) or use the default of delimiting on blanks, and replace `++n[$0]` with `++n[$1]` for instance to report the occurrence number of the first  field as opposed to the whole line.

Comment: Thank you :) really appreciate the in-depth explanation too, will help for future use!